# Disabling browserchannels in derbyjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, derbyjs

I found that even static pages (like error.js) in derby.js have an active connection with server. Maybe it makes sence for development (to have live updates for pages) but does it good for production? For example my main page is static but it keeps an active connection but I don't need in live update of this page (it changes monthly) and it is most visited page. And my question could (and should) I disable this active connection (browserchannel I guess) for static pages?

**UPD**:I think the active connection(I see progress indicator in firebug) is only when I go from a dynamic page to a static one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [static api](http://derbyjs.com/#static_pages) for generating pages, there should not be any js and live connection on these pages, just html and css. [Here](http://directory.derbyjs.com/static) is example of such static error page. Probably you do something wrong.

Comment: Thank you, yes, there is no active connection here, perhaps it was a kind of delay or bug in developer tools when i went from dynamic page to static